# A problem on finding the nearest points to the origin on the intersection of two surfaces

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, proof-verification, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose we are to find the points nearest to the origin on the curve of intersection of the two surfaces $g^{-1}_{1}\{ 0 \}$ and $g_{2}^{-1}\{ 0 \}$, where
$g_{1}: (x, y, z) \mapsto x^{2} - xy + y^{2} - z^{2} - 1$ and $g_{2}: (x, y, z) \mapsto x^{2} + y^{2} - 1.$ 
Since on $g_{1}^{-1}\{ 0 \} \cap g_{2}^{-1}\{ 0 \}$ we have 
$xy + z^{2} = 0,$
we may define
$g: (x, y, z) \mapsto xy + z^{2},$
so that $g^{-1}\{ 0 \} = g_{1}^{-1}\{ 0 \} \cap g_{2}^{-1}\{ 0 \}.$
Then we are to minimize the function $f: (x, y, z) \mapsto x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$ on $g^{-1}\{ 0 \}.$

If $(x, y, z) \in g^{-1}\{ 0 \}$ such that $f(x, y, z)$ is a local extremum and $\nabla g(x, y, z) \neq 0$, then there is a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\lambda \nabla f(x, y, z) = (2\lambda x, 2\lambda y, 2\lambda z) = \nabla g(x, y, z) = (y, x, 2z)$$

However, it seems to me that the vector equation above in combination with the constraint $g(x, y, z) = 0$ lead to $x = y = z = 0.$ Where did I commit an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really see any error in your computation. However you shouldn't drop one constraint. Instead you should keep the two simpler constraints

$$g_2(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-1\\
g(x,y,z)=xy+z^2$$

Use two parameters for Lagrange multiplier:

$$L=f(x,y,z)+\lambda g_2(x,y,z)+\mu g(x,y,z)$$

Then set up:

$$\nabla f+\lambda \nabla g_2 +\nabla g=0$$

together with the two constraints.

Try to continue from there. There are several cases to consider. You will get nontrivial solutions.

To answer your question about the geometry:
You can try letting $x,y,z$ be constants and visualize the cross-sections. They seem like parabola and hyperbola, and shrinking toward the origin. Now including the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, you'll get a closed curve (probably two). Notice that your objective function has level surfaces as spheres. Shrinking or enlarging them to touch the curve would give some maxima and\or minima.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure why combining the constraints leads to a trouble, ? Because doing that seems not to miss information, ?

Comment: Combining the constraints does not lead to trouble. It loses information though. In this case, the intersection of two surfaces would be a space curve. If you only use one equation, it can only give you a surface.

Comment: Thanks. Start to get a feeling of this stuff. But then what is the geometric meaning of the single surface I obtained?

Comment: If you meant $xy+z^2=0$, it is hard to describe. I'll edit the answer to briefly describe it.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Thanks for taking the trouble to write :)

Comment: Indeed, your answer fits exactly what I was asked. My question now is just this possible contradiction: "Combining two constraints is not sufficient to represent the intersection geometrically" and "Algebraically it seems that combining two constraints is sufficient to give the desired intersection".

Comment: Look at it in a linear system: $x+y=1,2x-2y=2$. This system has 1 unique solution, a point. If you combine them $3x-y=3$. Is it sufficient to represent the intersection?

Comment: Ah, I see. Nice illustration. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: KittyL-- isnt the Lagrange equation gradient(f) = (lambda1)gradient(g1) + (lambda2)gradient(g2)

Comment: @Dsmith: That gives you the same result. It's just the matter of the signs of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.